# Adding a component into a div

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a div and then add a component into that div during runtime. I was wondering how i could do this.

this is my components html:

```
<p>
<label >name</label>
</p>
```

this is my components ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-newcomp',
templateUrl: './newcomp.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./newcomp.component.css']
})
export class NewcompComponent implements OnInit {

 name: string;
 constructor() {
 }

  ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

This is where it will be called

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NewcompComponent } from './newcomp/newcomp.component';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';
 constructor() {
   this.Newcomp();
 }

 Newcomp() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');

  document.body.appendChild(div); 

  <-- this is where the component is added to the div, how can i achieve this.   

  } 
}
```

If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Also i know this example is simple, but keeping it simple will allow for clarity in the answer.

Comment: the best thing would be to look at Dynamic Components

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to dynamically add a component like that?

Comment: It's not recommanded to use javascript update DOM function like appendChild() in Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NewcompComponent } from './newcomp/newcomp.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  component: Type<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.component = this.newcomp();
  }

  private newcomp() {
    // use this method for logic
    return NewcompComponent;
  } 
}
```

In app.component.html add:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
```

For more info [Angular's component outlet info](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) & [Angular's dynamic component creation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Thanks this helped me.